# asynchronous http.get callbacks in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In Node, I have this function snippet (greatly reduced from the actual function, so hopefully I didn't cut anything important out):

```
Driver.prototype.updateDevices = function() {
    for (ip in this.ips) {
        var curIp = ip;
        if (this.ips[curIp]) {  // in case this.ips[curIp] is set to undefined...
            http.get(
                {   host: curIp,
                    port: 80,
                    path: '/tstat'
                },
                function (res) {
                    var result = '';
                    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                        result += chunk;
                    });
                    res.on('end', function () {
                        // Want to parse data for each ip, but
                        // curIp is always the last ip in the list
                    });
                }
            );
        };
    };
};
```

What I have is the "Driver" object, which contains "ips", an object containing a list of ip addresses, such as {"192.168.1.111":{stuff},"192.168.1.112":{stuff}}

Surely this is something very obvious that I'm overlooking, but I can't get it to work as expected. obviously, http.get() is called multiple times asynchronously. That is what I want; however, when the result is obtained and the "end" callback function is called, I can't access the "curIp" variable, which I want to contain the original ip address for the particular request being called back from. Instead the "curIp" variable always contains the last ip address in "this.ips". What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curIp` is not scoped to the `for` loop, it's scoped to the enclosing `updateDevices` function so it's shared by all `http.get` calls and is overwritten each time through the `for` loop.

The typical way to fix this is to create an immediate function that creates its own scope which can capture each iteration's `curIp` value as a parameter to that function:

```
if (this.ips[curIp]) {
    (function(ip) {    // Immediate function with its own scope
        http.get(
            {   host: ip,
                port: 80,
                path: '/tstat'
            },
            function (res) {
                var result = '';
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    result += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function () {
                    // ip is the captured ipCur here
                });
            }
        );
    })(curIp);   // Pass curIp into it as the ip parameter
};
```

Comment: Ha thanks that did it. I remember reading about this this little "quirk" with javascript but never put it completely together. Thanks